# Why do summation of Values appear under Pivot Table Column

Tags: excel, pivot-table, powerpivot

Software: MS Excel 2016 Pivot Table

EXCEL File: [GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RanaDataViz/Values)

---

I am creating pivot table where `Months Since Open` is under Rows and `Total Incidents`, `% Closed` is under Values

[image]

Please explain why summation of Values automatically appears under Columns

[image]

Comment: Because there's more than 1 summary and by default summaries are located in columns (B,C) , you can drag it to Rows area and have summaries in 2 rows.

Comment: That is the default setting.  You can turn it off if you want.